# Adding async method to Mongoose find

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to simplify the process of taking a documents file attribute and converting to the temp S3 link on the fly. Normally I have been grabbing all documents in the controller and then looping through and replacing the links before passing to the view. This works but can be a little messy if the controller logic is complex. I am trying to write a custom method for my schema where these links are replaced more easily. The following prints out the link in the console but shows undefined in the view because of the wonderful async nature of javascript. Is there a similar way to get this to work?

Maybe create a method similar to the way populate works?

**ExampleSchema.js:**

```
exampleSchema.methods.getS3Link = function(file_name, callback) {
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: file_name,
        Expires: 6000
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); //prints out the correct link
        return data; //shows undefined in view
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `callback` argument for `getS3Link` function. You can pass the `data` in this callback function to retrieve it in view.

```
exampleSchema.methods.getS3Link = function(file_name, callback) {
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: file_name,
        Expires: 6000
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); //prints out the correct link
        callback(null, data);
    })
}
```

Simpler:

```
exampleSchema.methods.getS3Link = function(file_name, callback) {
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: file_name,
        Expires: 6000
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params, callback);
}
```